# How to deploy a custom jar file into maven central repository to use in pom.xml as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar, pom.xml

I would like to know how to deploy a custom jar file into maven central repository to use in pom.xml as a dependency for other developers in their maven projects. I have followed several documentations for this. But I couldn't deploy it to maven central repository.

Comment: I assume you want to promote or publish your jar into maven repo. you can can follow this [tutorial](http://kirang89.github.io/blog/2013/01/20/uploading-your-jar-to-maven-central/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to the top directory of the project where your pom.xml and follow [these basics](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) -

> In a build environment, use the following call to cleanly build and
>   deploy artifacts into the shared repository.
>
> ```
> mvn clean deploy
> ```
>
> The same command can be used in a multi-module scenario (i.e. a
>   project with one or more subprojects). Maven traverses into every
>   subproject and executes clean, then executes `deploy` (including all
>   of the prior build phase steps).

Comment: The OP asks for deploying to MavenCentral, not just any Maven repository.